# Issue running express in MERN stack

Tags: express, router, middleware, mern

This is the error I got on running `npm start`:

```
F:\Works\Projects\Node\Voice_pres_withbackend\api\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:458   
      throw new TypeError('Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a ' + gettype(fn))
      ^

TypeError: Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a string
    at Function.use (F:\Works\Projects\Node\Voice_pres_withbackend\api\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:458:13)
    at Function.<anonymous> (F:\Works\Projects\Node\Voice_pres_withbackend\api\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:220:21)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Function.use (F:\Works\Projects\Node\Voice_pres_withbackend\api\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:217:7)
    at Object.<anonymous> (F:\Works\Projects\Node\Voice_pres_withbackend\api\app.js:25:5)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:956:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:973:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:812:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:849:19)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! api@0.0.0 start: `node ./bin/www`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the api@0.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-09-21T14_50_24_855Z-debug.log
```

This is part of the code the error is pointing to :

```
var express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();

router.get("/", function (req, res) {
  res.send("Api successful");
});

module.exports = router;
```

Can you please tell me what it is that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Try `module.exports = router;`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried, but I'm getting the same error